# Are there any adverse side effects to loading html5shiv in every browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

On the [*html5shiv* Google Code page](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) the example usage includes an IE conditional:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

However on the [*html5shiv* github page](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv), the description explains:

> This script is the defacto way to enable use of HTML5 sectioning
>   elements in legacy Internet Explorer, as well as default HTML5 styling
>   in Internet Explorer 6 - 9, **Safari 4.x** (and **iPhone 3.x**),
>   and **Firefox 3.x**.

An obvious contradiction. So to satisfy my curiosity, for anyone who has studied the code, are there any adverse side affects to loading *html5shiv* in every browser (without the IE conditional)?

EDIT: My goal, obviously, is to use the shiv without the IE conditional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that conditional comment on googlecode's page (updated probably more than a year ago) is because IE8 and below need a [javascript trick](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/) to allow *css styling* of HTML5 elements.

FF4, Safari 4, Opera 11  and below just don't apply `display:block` as default to "unknown" elements, but you only need a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to change this behaviour.

What html5shiv does on these browsers is just to add a `<style>` at the beginning of `<head>`, similar to this one:

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
```

Source: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

So, it ***should not*** give any side effect, because these rules can be overwritten by successive declarations.

As long as you add that rule on top of your main CSS file, it's ok to conditionally include html5shiv for IE only, you'll save an http request.

<strike>If you want your html5 website to be compatible with FF2 too (if so, you're a maniac), [check this tutorial](http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/).</strike>

OP discovered html5shiv already provides a fallback for FF2 !

Comment: Thanks. For anyone interested, html5shiv also solves the FF2 problem as long as the client has JavaScript enabled in their UA.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, i didn't know it! They should write it in their GitHub :)

Comment: If that's all html5shiv does, why not just add the block to your main CSS file and be done with it? If your site is browsed to by ancient browser, it helps, and if they use a modern browser, it won't do any harm. Right?

Comment: @ClayShannon html5shiv provides a javascript fallback required for IE8, so these css lines aren't enough to guarantee a full cross-browser compatibility. Until IE8 becomes extinct ;-)